# Inject a service from a library

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I am trying to inject a service from a 3rd party UI library. One of the UI components helps us create pop-up notifications.

To do this, we need to

1. Inject their notification service
2. Call the `runNotification` method with our message

```js
constructor(private notificationService: NotificationService){
  notificationService.runNotification('hi');
}
```

However, I am running into a `nullInjectorError: No Providers for NotificationService` error

### So Far I have tried to

1. Import their `NotificationModule` in my `module.ts`(ts+angular imports)
2. #1+ import the `NotificationService` in my `component.ts`
3. #1 + import the `NotificationService` into my module.ts

None of the above have helped.

I have also tried adding `NotificationService` to my providers. While this does fix the `nullInjectorError` for `NotificationService`. Another `nullInjectorError` pops up for `AppendService`

And `AppendService` isn't public so I am not able to import it within my code

Any ideas on what's wrong?

Comment: `no providers` errors mean just that - the service is not provided in the module that the component (or service) is inside of.

Comment: Wait, I did try to provide the service inside my component, but then I was getting a `NullInjector` error on a dependency of the `NotificationService`

Comment: Well it's just like you say, you need to provide everything nescessary for DI to work. If it's a 3rd party library this is usually done through modules that can be imported, just like angulars `FormBuilder`, which is provided in `FormsModule`

Comment: I have imported the `NotificationModule` within my feature `module.ts`. Maybe I should try importing it withing my core `app.module.ts`?

Comment: I'm a dumbass, your comparision with `formBuilder` helped a ton. I had been looking for other 3rd party libraries for similar code samples without realizing angular itself was a library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had imported the module in my `module.ts`, imported the service in my `component.ts` **and** added it in the providers array

For anyone else, coming across the same issue. You want to

1. Import the module in your `module.ts`
2. Import the service in your `component.ts`
3. Inject the service in your constructor

As [Mike S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13258211/mike-s) stated, injecting a service from a 3rd party library is just like importing `formBuilder`